# how to upload image into specific folder and rename it using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

so i have this function in my controller, but i don't know how to implement it in my view, i manage to upload the image into the database but the image that i upload didnt show up in any folder only in database and also i want to rename the image into the date:month:year(timestamp), what do i miss?

**Controller**

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '500';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('foto'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Foto</label>
        <input type="file" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/barang/do_upload');?>" name="foto" id="foto" class="form-control">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Tambah</button>
```

**EDIT**

so i've been dying to do this stuff, do some research and read a lot of articles but none seems work, as far as i get my view was under `form action="admin/barang/insert"` , and that makes my 2nd form get ignore, in any way how do we call 2 action in the same form?

Comment: Does your uploads folder have write permissions? - In your `do_upload` success dump `$this->upload->data()`

Comment: yes it have write permission, what do u mean with `do_upload` success dump?

Comment: Output `$this->upload->data()` if `do_upload` is successful, so you can see what data is actually being stored and where

Comment: already did that, but it's seem nothing happen, did i call function properly in my view?

Comment: is that action inside form action?

Comment: yes it is, why? we can't do that? @Yoshioka

Comment: @banzilla, not quite sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was fixed, instead making a new function `do_upload()` in **Controller**, i put what inside `do_upload()` function into my `insert()` function, so my `insert()` function have something like this

```
    //photo
    $photoName = gmdate("d-m-y-H-i-s", time()+3600*7).".jpg";
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/barang';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif||jpg||png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['file_name'] = $photoName;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){           
        $upload = 1;
    }
    else{
        $upload = 2;
    }
```

and then put some if else statement that if upload success, the data will be update otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

On Your view :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/barang/do_upload');?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Foto</label>
      <?php echo form_upload('foto'); ?>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Tambah</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

On Your controller :

```
public function do_upload()
{
   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';//this is the folder where the image is uploaded
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
   $config['max_size'] = '500';
   $config['max_width']  = '1024';
   $config['max_height']  = '768';
   $config['file_name'] = 'enter new file name here';//rename file here

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   $this->upload->initialize($config);

   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('foto'))
   {
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

       $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
   }
   else
   {
       $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

       $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
       $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.